# In .Net, why are these all called types?

Tags: .net, class, types, structure

In his book *Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform*, Andrew Toelsen says, "In the world of .NET, *type* is simply a general term used to refer to a member from the set {class, interface, structure, enumeration, delegate}.

What do these all have in common that they would be classed together as *types*? What would be a formal definition of *type* that would cover all of these under one umbrella term like that???

Comment: Presumably, "types" is a shortened form of **data types**.

Comment: What does _data type_ mean exactly? That you can store information somewhere with a name or pointer and refer to it later??

Comment: You know what a data type is. Just stop thinking about it in a programming context. This isn't something particularly esoteric or complicated. A number is a different type of data than some text. A person's address is a different type of data than their phone number which is a different type of data than their age. Defining types/data types in terms of *variables* and *pointers* and *structures* is definitely over-complicating things.

Comment: I know I'm overcomplicating it somewhat, I just want a semantic definition that I can wrap my mind around. I'm a little strange that way. I have to picture everything to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A type is anything that can describe a variable. For insstance, I can have a variable 'a' of type 'int' (int is a struct). I can also have 'b' of type 'MyClass' (MyClass is a class).

Basically, all type are used (more or less) in this way (to declare a variable):

```
TypeName variableName;
```

The newly declared variable automatically has some sort of internal structure, for example, if it is of a class type, it can have methods and properties. If is of a delegate type, then it is designed to hold a reference to a method.

Basically, a type is anything that you use to declare a variable. A type gives the variable its meaning, as well as restricts the variable to being used in a way which is suited to its existence.

Comment: So it's anything that can be declared as a grouping of data and/or functionality with a life of its own and that is stored somewhere?

Comment: Almost, except that the type itself doesn't really exist in a useable form - it's the variable that "exists" (this is a bit of a simplification). The type simply defines what the variable can/cannot do.

Comment: Ok. The type defines the behavior etc. of something you can create. It's the "mold" so to speak out of which you can create something useful (a variable) that "lives and breathes" on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can declare variables of these - a type defines the "kind of" or "structure" of a variable.

Technically, when you declare a variable of a certain type (for example, a class, an integral type etc.), you can only assign values of this specific type (or a compatible one, or one where an implicit type conversion exists) to the variable. In a strongly typed language like C#, in most cases the compiler will tell you if you break that rule.

Comment: Understand what that means as far as the words go, but what does that mean, technically??

Answer (score 0):

They're all types because they represent all the possible **types** of a variable. Simple! :)